# Dynamic shapes with CSS

Tags: html, transparency, css

I'm working on a creative project whereby I want to add 'triangles' to box elements to get a speech bubble effect and still apply an opacity to each element as shown below:

[image: CSS blocks with speech bubble effect and opacity]

I can get the blocks to display correctly with a 1px boarder on the right and bottom of each element. This, however, does not include the arrows on the heading element. When I add the arrows, using `.heading:before`, the result is as shown below:

[image: Because of the different elements' opcities, the original boarders are showing up]

As you can see, the original border remains, breaking the arrow and its corresponding element.

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <li class="heading">
        <div class="text_contain_head">
            <h1>Heading</h1><p>Subheading</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="options">
        <div class="text_contain">
            <h2>Option 1</h2><p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="options">
        <div class="text_contain">
            <h2>Option 2</h2><p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="options">
        <div class="text_contain">
            <h2>Option 3</h2><p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="options">
        <div class="text_contain">
            <h2>Option 4</h2><p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

and here's the CSS for .options:

```
.options {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    height: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
```

and here's the CSS for .heading:

```
.heading {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    float:left;
}

.heading:before {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    border: solid 20px transparent;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    z-index: 1002;

    transform:scale(1,1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1,1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1.5);
}
```

P.S. I use `:after` to add a white triangle with a 1px offset underneath the `:before` to replicate the border around the triangles.

In the end, I want to be able to keep the elements' opacities (due to the background image) and still be able to 'remove' the original border where the arrows overlap.

I'm stumped, as such any and all advice would be most apreciated

here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/N2nZ6/1/

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this when using non-opaque elements - the border around the element will always show through. It's a real shame you can't, but there it is.

Comment: Curses! I really didn't want to use img elements as it will slow down download time. Also, will become even slower due to hover effects on options 1 through 4. Thanks for reading though!

Comment: You could mitigate the image download time by building the images into a Sprite, therefore combining however many needed images into one request. Not quite sure how you are doing everything here and whether Sprites would work, but its one to think about maybe?

Comment: can you post a working example of what you got so far on jsfiddle? (tried but your css is incomplete) I would love to give this a try with pure css...

Comment: sure thing just give me a sec

Comment: Can you show an example of the hover effect for options 1 - 4 (and how the heading should look while the mouse is over one of the options)? Depending on the type of hover effect needed, that might determine how the heading has to be implemented.

Comment: Sure just check our the jsfiddle at the end of the post, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put up a fiddle of my own: http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/8WBcQ/

It was not easy, but i think i got away with it, but with some limitations:
 - I had to add two empty nodes inside your .heading for the arrows. I know it isn't pretty, but I tried without them and just couldn't get it to work.
 - I had to set a fixed width. It might be possible to do with percentages, but as it requiers very exact positioning, I did not even try... (percentages and exact postioning are a no go in my experience)

How does it work:
 - I turn the extra nodes into a square and rotate them 45deg to make them look like an arrow point
 - I position them absolute over the edge of the .heading, to cover up the border.
 - I set them to overflow hidden to prevent the :after and :before overflowing
 - I set the background image on the :before, counter rotate 45deg, and position exactly to line up with the background image of the ul
 - I add another :after with a the same semi-transparent background color as the .heading to  make the backgrounds match exactly.

It is not exactly clean, and it will take some fiddling with the positioning, but it works (in chrome, other browsers might need some prefixes). I don't dare to look at the result in older IE's. Might not be useable in a real life website, but as a proof of concept...

In real life I would probably go for a sprite image with the borders and arrows already in place, and position the li's on top of them.

And because SO insists, here is a part of the css:

```
.arrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 200px;
    left: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin-left: -25px;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
}
.arrow-down:after {
    content:' ';
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://www.placekitten.com/900/600);
    background-position: -114px -77px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -150px;
}
.arrow-down:before {
    content:'';
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the same basic approach I was considering: displaying the bg image separately for the arrows. Here's an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WBcQ/1/) with the hover effect added to options 1 - 4, to show that the overlapping arrows don't get doubly darkened by the hover effect (which is the key part of this).

Comment: Very creative solution! 1 up! pitty about the cross-browser compatibility though, but nice one! I'll play around with it and see what I can do thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I think that achieving this effect is a bit complicated which can be done by making the triangle opaque and keeping the same background image(using appropriate position) for the triangles which would cover the border.